# Pickup text for alert from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have created a table in HTML and table is having multiple columns and rows. Some of my columns are containing text and beside that text there is an image. After clicking on the image, i want to show alert of the text (93 in the below example).

```
<td id="Anumber">
  <div id="number5">
    93
    <a href="javascript:OrganiseValue()" onclick="this.className='btn_callOrg aM mL5'" 
      class="btn_callBl aM mL5"></a>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, but the anchor tag `<a>` is empty, so you won't be able to trigger `OrganiseValue()`

Comment: Yes a is empty... you need to wrap the div inside a instead of wrapping a inside the div. Or something like that. But I don't quite understand all you are writing.
But it looks like very weird way to do this.

Comment: hey sry fr confussion, the css class which is used contains an image and at after onclick also the class which is used is also a css which contains an image.

i'm so sorry..

Comment: Subrat, please update you question for the above clarification.

Comment: There isn't even an image in the HTML…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a full working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> 
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#number5").click(function() {
      alert("value: "+ $("#number5").html());
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="number5">
  93  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My guess is that it doesn't work for you because:

```
<a href="javascript:OrganiseValue()" onclick="this.className='btn_callOrg aM mL5'" 
class="btn_callBl aM mL5">******</a>
```

You have nothing where I put the stars `*******` so the `<a href..></a>` surrounds nothing - and nothing is something which is very hard to click on...

Answer (score -1):

```
<div>
  93
  <a onclick="alert(this.previousSibling.nodeValue)"></a>
</div>
```

`this` is set to the `<a>` element in the `onclick` handler so you can walk the DOM tree to get the text you need.